# My Javascript prompt runs before function even if prompt is located after the function

Tags: javascript, function, events, prompt

I wrote a small practice program that shows the times table for a prompted number.

I want the table to be shown after the user is asked for which number. If the user enters a different than -1 number, I want to ask for another number.

The sequence that I'm looking for is prompt the user, show the table, prompt the user show the table ... Unfortunately the sequence in which my program works is prompt the user, prompt the user, prompt the user ... AND JUST AFTER THAT show the tables for each input.

Obviously the code is not written in that way.

```js
  // get number to show time table for
  var aNumber = prompt("Enter the number for time table or -1 to stop the program", ""); 
  
  while(aNumber != -1) {
   timeTableFrom(aNumber); // show time table for the first number
   aNumber = prompt("Enter the number for time table or -1 to stop the program", ""); // ask for another number. HERE IS THE PROBLEM - THIS LINE RUNS BEFORE THE PREVIOUS ONE!
   
  }
  
  document.write("stopped");
  
    
  
  function timeTableFrom(number)
  {
   for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
   {
    document.write(number + " * " + i + " = " + number*i + "<br />");
   }
   
  }
```

Comment: `while` loop blocks the only thread the browser has, there's no time for rendering the results before the JS execution ends. You've to use a [timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers) to achieve what you want. (And replace `document.write` with a proper DOM manipulation function.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can help us help you by formatting your code so we don't have scroll it.

Comment: @zhon Thank you for your warm welcome. I will format it better next time. Will you provide a solution too?

Answer (score -1):

```js
// get number to show time table for
var aNumber = null;
var div = document.getElementById("textDiv");

setTimeout(enterNumber, 0);

function enterNumber()
{
  aNumber = prompt("Enter the number for time table or -1 to stop the program", ""); 

  if (aNumber != -1) {
    timeTableFrom(aNumber); // show time table for the first number
    setTimeout(enterNumber, 0);
  }
  else
    div.innerHTML += "stopped"
}

function timeTableFrom(number)
{
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
  {
    div.innerHTML += number + " * " + i + " = " + number*i + "<br />";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="textDiv">
</div>
```

@Teemu is correct.  And I admit, it's a bit sloppy, but this should work.  Try to avoid using document.write as it can have unpredictable results.  Instead try other [methods of output](http://binarynectar.com/output-techniques-in-javascript/)